# cannot build iOS react native app on Mac m1 Xcode 13.1 that previously built successfully on Intel

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react-native project that works perfectly when building using Mac intel. Now I'm switching to a MacBook 14 m1 pro with the same Xcode version 13.1 as on the Mac intel.

Both m1 and intel share the same settings for building for simulator and archiving for production.

However, on the Mac m1 when building for simulator doesn't work(specifically when building autofill credential provider extensions), it fires an error of undefined symbol for :

On the other hand, building archive for production works correctly on m1 like Intel.

More specifically is this error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` which never happens on my Mac intel.

Update: Weirdly when running npx react-native run-ios it built and run successfully :))

[image]

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?
What version of iOS / macOS are you targeting?

Comment: it's 0.64.2 for react native, iOS target 10.0, Extension target iOS 12.1

Comment: Go into xcode -> build settings and add 'arm64' under Excluded architecture

Comment: that does not work but weirdly when run npx react-native run-ios it built and run successfully :))

Answer (score 0):

A workaround this is running npx react-native run-ios or react-native run-ios instead of opening Xcode and build from it

Updated:

Add this to your Podfile, your project should be able to run from XCode:

```
post_install do |installer|
 react_native_post_install(installer)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
  end
 end
end
```